# How do we make new command like "\newcommand{\eql}[2]{\begin{align}\label(#2)}#1\end{align}}"

Tags: macros, labels

How do we make  new command like

```
\newcommand{\eql}[2]{\begin{align}\label(#2)}#1\end{align}}
```

which does not work with "\label(#2)" in there?
I just want to include the label number as a parameter as well.
Thank you!

latexatha

Comment: The error is unrelated to the `\newcommand` you have `\label(#2)}`  when you intended `\label{#2}`

Comment: It is very bad practice to use a number as a `\label` Note `\label` is unrelated to the printed equation number which usually appears as  (2)  it is the internal identifier used for cross referencing.

Comment: Thank you, David. So, How do I do it?  How do It include the label in the macro?

Comment: Thank you, David. So, now do I do it? It does not accept your correction in your 1st message either: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \eql". Thank you again. latexatha

Comment: Even after you correct the syntax error pointed out by @DavidCarlisle and choose to ignore his sage advice regarding how (not!) to set equation labels, you will still face a problem if you generate a multi-line equation in the manner made possible by your macro: You'll either have to provide additional `\label` instructions or will have to live with some uncertainty as to *which line* in the multi-line expression is associated with the `\label` instruction.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do, the point about `align` is that it automatically numbers the lines, why do you just want to manually number the first line and automatically number the rest?????? Also I would not hide the `\begin{align}` in a macro it will mean that your editor or this site for example do not know it is math mode so can not offer context sensitive help and syntax colouring

Comment: To echo the question of "what are you actually trying to do".  How are you intending to use this macro?  How should the macro's expansion look (in other words, what should the `\begin{align}...\end{align}` look like for the corresponding macro)?  How are you intending the resulting pdf to look?  Are you really wanting the `\tag` macro instead of the `\label` macro?

Comment: The macro \newcommand{\eq}{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}} works fine. I just want to add \label{ } to it. That's all. Thank you.